# jQuery - animate moving elements with no overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make my menu items move to random positions without overlapping on top of each other. I'm using `animate` with `top` `left` and obviously for those to work I set the position property to `absolute`.

Now the problem with this approach is that they will go across on top of each other when I just want them to bounce off on each other.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
function Menu($item) {
    this.item = $item;
};

Menu.prototype.makeNewPosition = function ($container) {
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];
};


Menu.prototype.move = function () {
    var that = this;
    $.each(this.item, function(index, value) {
        var newq = that.makeNewPosition($(value).parent());

        $(value).animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, 2000, function() {
        that.move();
    });
    });
};

var $menu = new Menu($('.nav li'));
$menu.move();
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/wzmh63xb/19/)

Comment: You won't be able to do this easily with jQuery, you should give a look to tweenmax or an equivalent.